# WebView displaying text while loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

How can I display text "Loading..." or the "spinner" while the user is waiting for the WebView to load and while it is still blank?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sami's way is right.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog (@"webViewDidStartLoad");
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog (@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

You have two methods in the delegate that will be helpful to you:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

In the first method you can start the UIActivityIndicatorView, and in the second one stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an UIActivityIndicatorView to your view in Interface Builder, connect it to your code and use the delegate methods Sami already pointed out to show/hide the UIActivityIndicatorView (that's the spinner you're talking about)